# combine firstname and lastname display it as fullname in php

Tags: php, mysql

I created an success form viewing the full name of the user and his username and
password on the form after signing up, Now my problem is how to join first name and lastname as fullname and display it on my textbox. you can help me. thanks.

here is my sample success form code:

```
<form >

     <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top:60px;">
        <!-- Material input -->
        <label for="username" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"><strong>Name:</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="md-form mt-0">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" style="margin-left:55px; width:180px;" value="<?php echo $name?>" readonly="true">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

here is my sample query:

```
<?php 

include_once('connection.php');

$sql = "select concat(fname,'',lname) as name from visitor order by id DESC limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

          $fname=$row['fname'];
          $lname=$row['lname'];

}


?>
```

Comment: you will find name in `$row['name']`

Comment: Also, don't loop through your results, there will only ever be one result

Comment: $lastName=$fname.$lname . You have to concatenate the string

Comment: i concated fname , and lname, as name value="<?php echo $name?>" is say undefine index $name ,

Comment: Since you're already concating as 'name' in the query you just have one output: `$row['name']`

Comment: okay i'll try it sir

Comment: thank you all for the hep, sorry im just beginner